# Cleaning and splitting a dataset in R

Tags: r, regex, list, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that looks likes this (note that the length of the words keep varying, the point is that it's unpredictable). `VAR` is a factor:

```
                       VAR
1     AAA - BB (CC) [DDDD]
2 A - BBB - (CCCC) - [DDD]
3  AA - B - (CCC) - [DDDD]
```

I want to convert it into this:

```
    X      Y
1 AAA     BB
2   A    BBB
3  AA      B
```

In other words I would like to get rid of everything inside the "()" and "[]", including the brackets themselves, as well as all of the dashes, and split the reminder into two variables as shown. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex with capturing group matching your AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD.
Basically, write a normal regex that matches your format:

Here a very broad regex because not sure what your "AAA" stands for:

```
[^ -]+[ -]+[^ -]+[ -]+\\([^ -]*\\)[ -]+\\[[^ -]*\\]
```

Please look up a basic regex course if you are unfamiliar with them.

Then you add parenthesis around what you want to extract ; this creates capture groups. Here I added parenthesis around the bits matching AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD:

```
([^ -]+)[ -]+([^ -]+)[ -]+\\(([^ -]*)\\)[ -]+\\[([^ -]*)\\]
```

Now, we can simply use this regex to extract the relevant groups.

The function `str_match` from package `stringr` can be used to extract the capture groups. (I generally recommend against using R base regex utilities as I find their syntax very inconsistent...)

```
VAR <- c("AAA - BB (CC) [DDDD]", 
         "A - BBB - (CCCC) - [DDD]",
         "AA - B - (CCC) - [DDDD]")

library(stringr)

str_match(VAR, "([^ -]+)[ -]+([^ -]+)[ -]+\\(([^ -]*)\\)[ -]+\\[([^ -]*)\\]")
```

Results:

```
     [,1]                       [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]  
[1,] "AAA - BB (CC) [DDDD]"     "AAA" "BB"  "CC"   "DDDD"
[2,] "A - BBB - (CCCC) - [DDD]" "A"   "BBB" "CCCC" "DDD" 
[3,] "AA - B - (CCC) - [DDDD]"  "AA"  "B"   "CCC"  "DDDD"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` by removing the substring from 'VAR' column using `sub` and read the `vector` with `read.table` to create a two-column `data.frame`

```
res <-  read.table(text=gsub("\\s+", "", sub("\\s*-*\\s+\\(.*", "", df1$VAR)), 
              sep="-", col.names = c("x", "y"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
res
#    x   y
#1 AAA  BB
#2   A BBB
#3  AA   B
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, VAR, into = c("x", "y"), "^(\\w+)\\W+(\\w+).*")
#    x   y
#1 AAA  BB
#2   A BBB
#3  AA   B
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(VAR = c("AAA - BB (CC) [DDDD]", "A - BBB - (CCCC) - [DDD]", 
 "AA - B - (CCC) - [DDDD]")), .Names = "VAR", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```